Qt Creator + Visual Studio 2022 compiler
I'm trying to build on Qt Creator with the VS compiler.

I have installed Qt 6.4.2 and VS2022.
It's just a Hello, world! project. If I choose Desktop Qt 6.4.2 MinGW 64-bit, it can be built. But if I choose Desktop(x86-windows-msvc2022..., it wont' work.
At first, it prompted no Najia generator, then I set it to Visual Studio 17 2022.

Then It still gives error with no cmake file. But the CMake file is under the project when it created.

If I recall it properly, the VS22 is a 64 bit application, so all the (hardcoded) paths are wrong when building.

Also, take a look at this They say, that from QT 6.8 MSVC22 is supported.

One more thing, Qt dropped x86 support (only keeping x64) since Qt5.15 - although, it is still possible to build the 32bit Qt binaries from source.
